# What's wrong with this T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What's wrong with this T-SQL :

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,[Value] VARCHAR(100))
SET @temp = dbo.[fnCSVToTable](',2,3')
```

Comment: The problem is in your function or the argument you are passing to it. 

Need the SQL for the function or the actual error message.

Comment: What does fncsvtotable look like? And like @pascal said an error message or description of what is going wrong would help?

Comment: Error Message: Must declare the variable '@temp'.

Comment: Function can be any table valued function, the actual code of function does not matter according to me, if there is an error in function that would be runtime.

Comment: 'Must declare the `scalar` variable @temp' ? You need to use the variable like a table have a look here http://odetocode.com/Articles/365.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can assign to the table variable like that (unless it is a new thing in SQL 2008).

At least for SQL2005 you would need to do the following.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,[Value] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @temp
SElECT [value] 
FROM dbo.[fnCSVToTable](',2,3')
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for `SET` ([SQL 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx); [SQL 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484%28SQL.90%29.aspx)) (my emphasis):

> `@ local_variable`
>
> Is the name of a
>   variable of any type except cursor, text, ntext, image, **or table**.

To populate a table variable, use

```
INSERT @table_variable 
SELECT columns 
FROM dbo.fnTableValuedFunction
```

Comment: Docs say the following: There is no table included in the except clause.

@local_variable

Is the name of a variable of any type except cursor, text, ntext, or image. Variable names must begin with one at sign (@). Variable names must conform to the rules for identifiers. For more information, see Using Identifiers.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja added links to the relevant MSDN pages *which I am directly quoting*. The only such page I can find which *doesn't* mention `table` is the SQL *2000* page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259193%28SQL.80%29.aspx ), but SQL 2000 didn't *have* table variables, so naturally they are not mentioned.

Comment: Ok, its my mistake, but Sql 2000 have table variables and I am using this t-sql on sql 2000.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja my mistake too (neglected to check which version they were introduced in); and also it would appear to be a mistake in the SQL 2000 docs (omitting to mention that `SET` doesn't work with table variables) !